# How to write an extension method that returns a dynamic object?

Tags: c#, dynamic, .net-4.0, extension-methods, c#-4.0

I was thinking about how Regex.Match.Group wants to be dynamic:

```
Regex.Match (...).Groups["Foo"]
```

would like to be:

```
Regex.Match (...).Groups.Foo
```

---

I thought about writing an extension method that would allow:

```
Regex.Match (...).Groups().Foo
```

And tried writing it this way, but this isn't allowed (';' required by 'static dynamic')

```
public static dynamic DynamicGroups Groups(this Match match)
{
    return new DynamicGroups(match.Groups);
}

public class DynamicGroups : DynamicObject
{
    private readonly GroupCollection _groups;

    public DynamicGroups(GroupCollection groups)
    {
        this._groups = groups;
    }
    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        Group g = this._groups[binder.Name];

        if (g == null)
        {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            result = g;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Any way to accomplish this?**

There are plenty of other APIs that were written before `dynamic` that might be cleaner to use this way.

Comment: This is such a good example of why dynamic is not getting close to any code I have control over. The only thing you achieve with this is that you have something that looks statically typed but is not.

Comment: @erik: A very real concern. I decided to see if it was possible before seeing if I liked it. I was thinking about calling the extension method `DynamicGroups()` to make it clear. What do you think?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's just one little error in your code, change `dynamic DynamicGroups` to just `dynamic`

```
public static dynamic Groups(this Match match)
{
    return new DynamicGroups(match.Groups);
}
```